# Push Notifications stopped working after recent update

Tags: iphone, ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Hi I have an app on the App Store which used to receive Push Notifications perfectly but after a recent update it seems to have stopped.

I have not changed any of the notification code so I was wandering if there have been any changes in iOS 5.1 which may be causing the issue.

Anyone had a similar experience and know how to fix it?

In the application delegate I am registering for notifications:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

and implementing the following methods:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Comment: "A recent update" of iOS or your app? If your app, I would make sure the archive was signed using the correct bundle identifier.

Comment: It was an update of my app, just double checked the bundle identifier and it is exactly the same as the previous versions which worked fine.

Comment: Hopefully you're using version control and can look through your changes to see where you went wrong. 

If you haven't made any changes, then you've likely singed using the wrong bundle identifier, push notifications aren't being sent from the server correctly, etc.

Comment: Yeah I've checked all previous versions and the bundle id is the same, I have also checked with the server which shows the notifications are being sent - just not received.